# What is the source of this information about Batman Beyond and DCAU?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe, batman-beyond

Information from the wikis on how far in the future ***Batman Beyond*** is supposed to be, as compared to DCAU's set-in-the-'present' Batman properties, goes:

> Though it is not directly stated, Bruce Wayne's final fight takes place thirty years after Batman: The Animated Series, twenty years after The New Batman Adventures, and ten years after Justice League. <sup>[[1]](http://dcanimated.wikia.com/wiki/Rebirth)</sup>

and again

> The pilot episode, titled "Rebirth," initially begins in the year 2019, 20 years after The New Batman Adventures. ... The story fast-forwards to 2039 in Neo-Gotham, a futuristic megalopolis featuring staggering high rises and flying vehicles. <sup>[[2]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Beyond)</sup>

**What is the source of this information?**

Comment: You are working too hard. Each DC continuum has a slightly different timeline and none of them give you specific dates or ages for Batman because they don't want to pin exactly how old he is at any given moment in the mainline continuum. He is perpetually 25-30 in the mainstream DC Universe. All of the estimates to Batman's age in each different continuum are exactly that, estimates. I doubt seriously if anyone gave an exact number if they could help it. It is part of the comic business that heroes rarely get old and if they do, it's time to REBOOT the Universe...

Comment: That is true for comics, but DCAU is one consistent universe which has, to my knowledge, never been rebooted, and actually shows aged Bruce, Babs, Clark and even John and Shayera's kid, not to mention the tie-in episode bomb that was "Epilogue". If it has ever been rebooted, then any creator comment to that affect will also be welcome as an answer :)

Comment: I am betting you will never get a starting age for Batman because DC has always been vague about that number for all of its heroes. I have seen every episode of the DCAU (multiple times) and I have no record of ever having Batman's age revealed on the air.

Comment: I'd have to agree with Thaddeus on this, I read the Batman Beyond comics that are currently being published and it's even less vague (if that's possible) about when they take place.  You might do best to just sit back and enjoy the series for what it is, a good time!

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza I have also been enjoying the BB:Comics but they do not seem to be the same kind of 'set' continuity when compared to the TV shows.

Comment: @Thaddeus While no concrete ages (other than Terry's) have been mentioned on show to my knowledge, there are definitely often nuggets of 'number of years since X' kind. Plus, even if (B) is not answerable, part (A) should be, and neither is really subjective, imo.

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered, even after doing ton of research. I don't think all these episodes are created to be **that** consistent, even if it is proclaimed that all of them take place in the same universe/timeline.

Comment: I don't agree that part B is unanswerable to the extent of being a bad question (which I presume is the reason for downvotes), but I take note of the crit and for the moment I have chosen to concentrate on part A, which is trying to source statements from the wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [*Modern Masters Volume 3: Bruce Timm*](https://books.google.com/books?id=EMwn_4llWK0C&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67&dq=Bruce+Timm+kid-friendly+Batman+Beyond+cartoon&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false), page 64, there are some sketches from Batman Beyond.

> This Page: Bruce Wayne at 60, with and without the bat-suit.

Pictured is the Batman Beyond suit he is wearing at the beginning of "Rebirth", when he decides to quit being Batman.

> Next Page Bottom: Bruce Wayne at age 80, as he appeared in *Batman Beyond*

In [IGN's History of Batman on TV](http://www.ign.com/articles/2008/07/17/a-history-of-batman-on-tv?page=8) they say

> Warner Brothers decided to try a reboot of the franchise, setting Batman Beyond more than forty years in the future.

Of course, they don't cite anything either. There are actually several citation free articles on the internet that also claim it is 40 years since The New Batman Adventures. Whether that is everyone feeding off the same trough of lies or not isn't clear though.

That being said, I think 40 years from New Batman Adventures, and possibly 30 years after JLA / JLU sounds about right.