# How old was Bruce Wayne in Batman Beyond?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe, batman-beyond

I can't really find any official/canonical/whatever-it's-called sources, but  [this random youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0bTCeUUoP0) at 0:49 says he was "in his 50s", and page 64 of the the book *Modern Masters Volume 3: Bruce Timm* says he was 80:

> Bruce Wayne at age 80, as he appeared in *Batman Beyond*.
>
> ([1](https://books.google.no/books?id=EMwn_4llWK0C&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67&dq=Bruce+Timm+kid-friendly+Batman+Beyond+cartoon&hl=en&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=60&f=false) , [2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/100652/23918))

(also 80s looks way more likely to me than 50s, but I'm no expert)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the show's [official website](http://web.archive.org/web/20060507183638fw_/http://www.batmanbeyond.com/HTML/index.html), Bruce is

> "***Late 70's, early 80's***"
>
> [image]

This tallies nicely with his age as portrayed in the show and tallies with the age of the younger(ish) Bruce seen in flashback in [Batman Beyond: Out of the Past](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Out_of_the_Past). Bruce is depicted as aging, but not elderly in 2009, thirty years before the main timeline.

Comment: on an unrelated note, ```Occupation: CEO of Wayne Enterprises``` that sounds wrong, i got the impression that Derek Powers was CEO and Bruce was still on some "board of directors" but mostly retired :o guess that should be a question of it's own though